# Parsing text in textbox VB

Tags: vb.net

I have data from Text file and copy textbox to like :

```
Booking Details / Detail Pemesanan
Booking ID/ Booking ID  78B8MMRZX67
Booking Status/ Status Booking  ISSUED
Booking Time / Waktu Booking    05-04-2022 (7:26)
Booking Expiration Time / Waktu Berakhir Booking    05-04-2022 (8:26)
Passenger Details / Detail Peminjam
Name / Nama Fidelia Ariadne Radi
Phone Number / Nomor Telepon Peminjam   +66821866961
Supplier Info / Info Penyedia
Company Name / Nama Perusahaan  Jayamahe Easy Ride Bali
Phone Number / Nomor Telepon    +628179094919
Route / Rute    DPS - Legian
Pick Up Location / Lokasi Jemput    Ngurah Rai International Airport (DPS), Denpasar, Indonesia
Pick Up Location Note / Catatan Lokasi Jemput   -
Drop Off Location / Lokasi Antar    Loft Legian Hotel, Jl. Melasti No.99, Legian, Kec. Kuta, Kabupaten Badung, Bali 80361, Indonesia
Drop Off Location Note /Catatan Lokasi Antar    -
Special Requests / Kebutuhan Khusus -
Flight Number / Nomor Penerbangan   3K - 241
Pick Up Time / Waktu Jemput Tuesday, 05 Apr 2022
14:00
Car Type / Jenis Mobil  Jayamahe Budget MPV
Inventory Type / Jenis Inventori    Standard
Passenger Capacity / Jumlah Penumpang   4
Baggage Capacity / Jumlah Bagasi    4
Number of Car / Jumlah Mobil    1
```

I Made generate from VB like:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim lines() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(CChar(Environment.NewLine))
        ' Dim name As String = lines(0).Replace("Name: ", "")
        ' Dim maths As Integer = CInt(lines(1).Replace("Maths: ", ""))
        ' Dim english As Integer = CInt(lines(2).Replace("English: ", ""))
        Dim idbooking As String = lines(1).Replace("Booking ID/ Booking ID  ", "")
        Dim wkbooking As String = lines(3).Replace("Booking Time / Waktu Booking    ", "")
        Dim expiredbooking As String = lines(4).Replace("Booking Expiration Time / Waktu Berakhir Booking   ", "")
        Dim nd As String = TextBox3.Text
        Dim jenismobil As String = lines(20).Replace("Car Type / Jenis Mobil    Jayamahe ", "")
        Dim Jumlahmobil As String = lines(24).Replace("Number of Car / Jumlah Mobil ", "")
        Dim rute As String = lines(11).Replace("Route / Rute    ", "")
        Dim flight As String = lines(17).Replace("Flight Number / Nomor Penerbangan ", "")
        Dim nama As String = lines(6).Replace("Name / Nama  ", "")
        Dim hp As String = lines(7).Replace("Phone Number / Nomor Telepon Peminjam  ", "")
        Dim wkjemput As String = lines(18).Replace("Pick Up Time / Waktu Jemput ", "")
        Dim timejemput As String = lines(19).Replace(" ", "")
        Dim lokasijemput As String = lines(12).Replace("Pick Up Location / Lokasi Jemput    ", "")
        Dim lokasiantar As String = lines(14).Replace("Drop Off Location / Lokasi Antar ", "")
        Dim note1 As String = lines(13).Replace("Pick Up Location Note / Catatan Lokasi Jemput  ", "")
        Dim note2 As String = lines(16).Replace("Special Requests / Kebutuhan Khusus    ", "")
    
        Dim note3 As String = lines(15).Replace("Drop Off Location Note /Catatan Lokasi Antar   ", "")
        Dim note4 As String = lines(16).Replace("Special Requests / Kebutuhan Khusus    ", "")
        Dim jumlahpenumpang As String = lines(22).Replace("Passenger Capacity / Jumlah Penumpang    ", "")
        Dim jumlahbagasi As String = lines(23).Replace("Baggage Capacity / Jumlah Bagasi    ", "")
    
    
        TextBox2.Text = "ID VOUCHER " + vbNewLine &
                        idbooking + vbNewLine &
                        "Waktu Pesanan : " + wkbooking + vbNewLine &
                        "Expired : " + expiredbooking + vbNewLine &
                        "Status : New" + vbNewLine + vbNewLine &
                        "*ND : " + nd + "*" + vbNewLine &
                        "Detail Pesanan" + vbNewLine &
                        "TRAVELOKA. Shuttle Car " + vbNewLine &
                        "Bali AT" + vbNewLine + vbNewLine &
                        "*Tipe Mobil :" + jenismobil + "*" + vbNewLine &
                        "Jumlah Mobil : " + Jumlahmobil + vbNewLine + vbNewLine &
                        "*Rute: " + rute + "*" + vbNewLine &
                        "*Flight No : " + flight + "*" + vbNewLine &
                        "Detail Penumpang " + vbNewLine &
                        nama + vbNewLine &
                        "*" + hp + vbNewLine + vbNewLine &
                        "Waktu Jemput : " + wkjemput + vbNewLine &
                        "*Pukul : " + timejemput + " " + ComboBox1.Text + "*" + vbNewLine &
                        "Lokasi Jemput " + vbNewLine &
                        lokasijemput + vbNewLine + vbNewLine &
                        "Note " + note1 + vbNewLine &
                        note2 + vbNewLine + vbNewLine &
                        "Lokasi Antar" + vbNewLine &
                        lokasiantar + vbNewLine &
                        "Note " + note3 + vbNewLine &
                        note4 + vbNewLine + vbNewLine &
                        "Jumlah Penumpang :" + jumlahpenumpang + vbNewLine &
                        "Jumlah Bagasi    :" + jumlahbagasi + vbNewLine
    
    End Sub
    
    
    
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        CopyAllMyText()
    End Sub
    Public Sub CopyAllMyText()
    
            TextBox2.SelectAll()
        ' Copy the contents of the control to the Clipboard.
        TextBox2.Copy()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Please help me to get result like this:

```
ID VOUCHER

78B8MMRZX67
Waktu Pesanan :
05-04-2022 (7:26)
Expired :
05-04-2022 (8:26)
Status : New

*ND : 560000*
Detail Pesanan
TRAVELOKA. Shuttle Car
Bali AT

*Tipe Mobil :Budget MPV*
Jumlah Mobil :
1

*Rute: DPS - Legian*
*Flight No : 3K - 241*
Detail Penumpang

Fidelia Ariadne Radi
*66821866961*

Waktu Jemput :
Tuesday, 05 Apr 2022
*Pukul : 14:00 WIT*

Lokasi Jemput

Ngurah Rai International Airport (DPS), Denpasar, Indonesia

Note
-

- 

Lokasi Antar

- 

Jumlah Penumpang :4
Jumlah Bagasi    :4
```

Comment: Is it correct that the time part of "Pick Up Time" is on a separate line?

Comment: but if copy to notepad++ result is
*Tipe Mobil :
Budget MPV*

Comment: I suspect that you need `vbCrLf` instead of `vbNewLine`, and `Dim lines() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(CChar(Environment.NewLine))` should be `Dim lines() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbCrLf, StringSplitOptions.None)`.

Comment: Error 1 Argument matching parameter 'separator' narrows from 'String' to '1-dimensional array of Char'. 

If I using Dim lines() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbCrLf, StringSplitOptions.None)

Comment: Oops! Correction: `Dim lines() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: while vbCrLf works, I prefer [`System.Environment.NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-6.0) instead, as its OS-agnostic and provides the right EOL char(s) for the OS it runs on.

Comment: @HelO'Ween System.Environment.NewLine is OS-dependent, whereas many file formats, e.g. [CSV](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180), have a system-independent line ending defined. So one or the other is required depending on the input and desired output. Guessing that the OP is on Windows and working with Windows-style text files, vbCrLf would survive the program being run under Linux if that ever happened.

Comment: @AndrewMorton you're right, I wasn't aware of that. TIL: [CSV has a defined EOL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).